# Storing units of measure from Pint in App Engine datastore (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to store units of measure along with the magnitude of measurement in the App Engine datastore. I really love the approach that the library [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) takes in that it feels very natural to describe a measurement, inspect its magnitude and units, and convert it to other units:

```python
from pint import UnitRegistry
units = UnitRegistry()

weight = 30 * units.lbf
print(weight.magnitude)
print(weight.units)
print(weight.to(units.kg))
```

However, it's not obvious to me how I would store these quantities in the App Engine datastore. How might one go about storing these in the App Engine datastore? Is there a more elegant approach than simply creating separate properties for the magnitude and unit? Is the best approach to write a custom Property? Ideally, all weight properties would be sortable regardless of unit of measure.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the easiest way is to store magnitude and units separately. Additionally, to speed up searching and sorting, you might want to store (maybe as Computed Properties) the magnitude converted to base units, the base units and the base dimensionality.